# Rails: Turbo Frame / Turbo Stream element is not rendered the SECOND time I trigger it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo

In a view that displays a list of categories, there is a little part underneath that shows the "default" of these categories. When a user clicks there, it is replaced by a drop down form where they can select the new default. Upon submitting of the form, the two parts of the page - list of categories as well as lower part where the default is shown - shall be updated via turbo stream.

This works once. If I try to click the lower element for the second time, the whole page renders blank even though the network tab of the browser shows that something is arriving. I don't understand why that happens.

view (index page):

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag 'settings-content' do %>
  <h3 class="heading4">Available book formats</h3>
  <ul class="simple-list width-33" id="book-formats">
    <%= render 'new_form_entry' %>
    <%= turbo_frame_tag 'format-list' do %>
      <%= render @book_formats %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <h3 class="heading4 margin-top-1 margin-bottom-50">Default Book Format</h3>
  <ul class="simple-list width-25">
    <li>
      <%= turbo_frame_tag 'default-format' do %>
        <%= render 'book_formats/set_default_form' %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

controller (relevant two methods):

```
  def set_default
    @book_formats = BookFormat.all.order(:name)
  end

  def update_default
    @new_default = BookFormat.find_by(name: book_format_params[:name])
    @default_book_format.update(fallback: false)
    @new_default.update(fallback: true)
    @default_book_format = @new_default
    @book_formats = BookFormat.all.order(:name)
  end
```

update_default.turbo_stream.erb

```
<%= turbo_stream.replace 'format-list' do %>
      <%= render @book_formats %>
<% end %>
<%= turbo_stream.replace 'default-format' do %>
      <%= render 'book_formats/set_default_form' %>
<% end %>
```

I am sure I am missing a small piece somewhere?

Comment: try `turbo_stream.update`

Comment: that did the trick. I have no clue why though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`turbo_frame_tag`](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/v1.1.1/app/helpers/turbo/frames_helper.rb#L38) helper renders a *<turbo-frame>* tag and the form:

```html
<turbo-frame id="default-format">
  <form>
    <!-- ... -->
  </form>
</turbo-frame>
```

[`turbo_stream.replace`](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/v1.1.1/app/models/turbo/streams/tag_builder.rb#L62) will **replace** the target *#default-format* with the template, in this case it is just the form:

```html
<turbo-stream action="replace" target="default-format">
  <template>
    <form>
      <!-- ... -->
    </form>
  </template>
</turbo-stream>
```

Which means *<turbo-frame>* goes away:

```html
<!-- target          identified by id -->
<!-- v               v                -->
    <turbo-frame id="default-format"></turbo-frame>

<!-- is replaced by -->
    <form></form>

<!-- end result -->
    <form></form>
```

There is no `#default-format` for the stream to replace the second time.

---

[`turbo_stream.update`](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/v1.1.1/app/models/turbo/streams/tag_builder.rb#L140) action keeps the target and only updates the contents.

```html
<!-- target          identified by id -->
<!-- v               v                -->
    <turbo-frame id="default-format"></turbo-frame>

<!-- target content is updated with -->
    <form></form>

<!-- end result -->
    <turbo-frame id="default-format">
      <form></form>
    </turbo-frame>
```

---

The target of the *turbo-stream* can be anything, not just *turbo-frame*:

```html
<!-- unless you're doing something else with this frame, 
     there is no need for it -->
<%= turbo_frame_tag "format-list" do %>
  <%= render @book_formats %>
<% end %>

<!-- just an `id` is enough for turbo-stream -->
<div id="format-list">
  <%= render @book_formats %>
</div>
```

---

*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/streams*

Comment: WOW! Yes, I read the documentation but I didn't understand it. Very clearly explained, thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, so what's the use case of `turbo_stream.replace`? One-time load events?

Comment: @FrankKoehl mostly it's used when partial you're rendering includes the `id` target you're trying to update (when you have `dom_id(model)` in the first line of the partial and you want to update that dom id)